# How to slow down preview playback?

Tags: animation

I'm working on an animation and am trying to get the timing to match the audio that I'm using. In other programs I've been able to just tell the program to slow down the playback (animation programs like SFM, or video editing like Sony Vegas/Adobe), so that I can make sure every shot is landing right where I want it, lipsync works, etc.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Blender. Is there no simple way to keep the video/audio synchronized while playing at a lower speed than realtime?